# Basic Apache Camel FileRoute deployed as OSGi bundle

Tags: osgi, apache-camel

I'm trying to do some "hello world" example with Apache Camel. Just a simple route, deployed as OSGi bundle to Apache Karaf. And it's crazy, too many things to learn at once, Camel itself, integration with spring, integration with OSGi and Karaf...ugh.

I'm trying to follow the idea from here: http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/wp/2008/10/19/simple-camel-dsl-osgi-bundle-example/.

I've created the bundle, the package with FileRoute.java file, etc, but I can't produce valid manifest.mf file, it's generated by "bundle plugin for maven" - so the POM file is used to generate the manifest file.

What's the problem is this in the manifest file, line with import packages:

```
Import-Package: com.company.foo.bar.demo;version="0.1",org.apache.ca
 mel.builder;version="2.10",org.apache.camel.model;version="2.10",org.
 apache.commons.logging
```

With error: "No available bundle exports package 'org.apache.camel.builder'" (and .model package).

Well, I understand what is the problem, but…How to expose these packages for the bundle?

Next I have there another bundle with Apache Camel context, so I thought that good idea is to expose the packages from there, through "export package", but it doesn't work, the camel bundle can't be build then.

I'm quite lost :( I'd really appreciate help or hint.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes OSGi deployments is a PITA, hence why it should/can be much easier with FAB (http://www.davsclaus.com/2012/08/osgi-deployment-made-easy-with-fab.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Apache Camel 2.10 or better then the Maven archetypes is a good place to start a new Camel project. We have archetypes that can create OSGi based project for either spring-dm or OSGi blueprint. You chose which one you want to use. The project is then ready for OSGi as it setup a maven plugin that generated the needed osgi stuff for you. Only in more advanced cases you would need to tweak this plugin.

See details at: http://camel.apache.org/camel-maven-archetypes.html

If you use Maven 3.0.x then its much easier as you can just type

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

Then it runs in interactive mode, then type camel to filter only camel archetypes.

And then select the number for the archetype. eg for example the spring-dm to use OSGi with Spring.

Comment: Hi! Yep, that looks good…So I guess this - http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-osgi-camel-part1.html - is completely out of date, right? (Yes, I know, there is the note that the tutorial is out-of-date, I mean, it's not compatible with camel-archetype-blueprint).

Comment: Yeah its out of date, it was from Camel 1.x time and also SMX/CXF/Karaf back then was much harder to use with OSGi. You can find links to OSGi tutorials here: http://camel.apache.org/articles, for example the one by Christian Schneider.

Comment: We love contributions though, so people is much welcome to update the tutorials to latest standards. However people tend to write their own blogs, instead of helping with the project docs :(

Comment: Well, I'd like to help you as you helped me :) No problem for me to write some tutorial, once I'll have clear knowledge how it really works :)

But, my texts really needs english revision, because, as you can see, my english is not really good as I'm from Czech Republic and I'm lazy to move on with my english education :P

Comment: No worries about the language. We have people in the team who speak native and some of them is good at polishing the text afterwards. And remember Apache projects is international projects, so a lot of non-native-english users and committers. Any contributions is welcome.